# iPhone's space problem

Tags: iphone, disk-space

Looking at my iPhone via iTunes, i see a very questionable amount of "Other".

What is it? How can i delete it?

[image]

Comment: If the "Other" is not in use, it should go away by itself soon.  If it really bothers you, try restarting the iPhone.

Comment: "'Other' represents settings, calendar events, notes, browser cache, email, email attachments, and more nonmedia data."

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, iTunes' space meter is fairly unreliable (by which I mean that I've seen it jump by gigabytes with no apparent cause, and occasionally say that my space was over the limit when that's obviously impossible).

On your iPhone, go to Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage to see exactly what's taking up all that space.